# C++ template design pattern for groups (algebra)

Tags: c++, reference-request, nonlinear-equations, design-patterns

Having both programmed my share of c++ and studied some beginners group theory some year ago, I got curious about this...

Is there any particularly popular template based (object oriented) design pattern for systematically programming any kind of stuff related to group theory?

Comment: I think this is too general a question. "Abstract algebraic concepts" is just too unspecified to allow saying anything about representation with templates.

Comment: Ok I can scratch the abstract algebraic concepts and stick with group theory. But I had enough of trouble to manage to find tags to fit the question already.

Comment: A comment rather than an answer: translating the math. structure into templates, though natural, is not always beneficial to software design (sometimes it's good, sometimes it makes it more complicated with no benefit)

Comment: @BrunoLevy : Yes I know it is not always beneficial. But I would suspect something with so many rules and structures as algebra would benefit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapters 6 and 7 of [Stepanov and Rose's book From Mathematics to generic programming](http://www.fm2gp.com/) deal precisely with what you asked. The first author is the designer of the C++ Standard Template Library.

Comment: Clever choices, definitely. Almost mindblastingly clever. Almost presidentially clever, even.

Answer (score 2):

An earlier alternative to Stepanov's treatment of abstract algebra (including groups) is the one given in Barton and Nackman's "Scientific and Engineering C++".

In more modern c++, the [boost concept checking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) library would seem to be a quite natural means of modularising the hierarchy of algebraic types (semigroups, monoids, groups etc).